# Star Trek: SCE - How many books?

Tags: star-trek, short-stories, books, star-trek-eu

I just have to know: how many books are in the series [Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers (ST:SCE)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Starfleet_Corps_of_Engineers). On-line is a option if you want to include those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There are 87

Here's a list.

> The Belly of the Beast by Dean Wesley Smith 1
> Fatal Error by Keith R. A. DeCandido 2
> Hard Crash by Christie Golden 3
> Interphase, Part One of Two by Dayton Ward 4
> Have Tech, Will Travel by Keith R. A. DeCandido omnibus 1-4
> Interphase, Part Two of Two by Dayton Ward 5
> Cold Fusion by Keith R. A. DeCandido 6
> Invincible, Part One of Two by David Mack 7
> Invincible, Part Two of Two by David Mack 8
> Miracle Workers by Keith R. A. DeCandido    omnibus 5-8
> The Riddled Post by Aaron Rosenberg 9
> Here There Be Monsters by Keith R. A. DeCandido 10
> Ambush by Dave Galanter 11
> Some Assembly Required by Scott Ciencin 12
> Some Assembly Required [omnibus] by Greg Brodeur    omnibus 9-12
> No Surrender by Jeff Mariotte 13
> Caveat Emptor by Ian Edginton 14
> Past Life by Robert Greenberger 15
> Oaths by Glenn Hauman 16
> No Surrender by Mike Collins    omnibus 13-16
> Foundations, Book One of Three by Dayton Ward 17
> Foundations, Book Two of Three by Dayton Ward 18
> Foundations, Book Three of Three by Dayton Ward 19
> Foundations by Dayton Ward  omnibus 17-19
> Enigma Ship by J. Steven York 20
> War Stories, Book One of Two by Keith R. A. DeCandido   21
> War Stories, Book Two of Two by Keith R. A. DeCandido   22
> Wildfire Book 1 (Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers 23) by David Mack  23
> Wildfire Book 2 by David Mack   24
> Wildfire by Keith R. A. DeCandido   omnibus 20-24
> Home Fires by Dayton Ward   25
> Age of Unreason by Scott Ciencin    26
> Balance of Nature by Heather Jarman 27
> Breakdowns by Keith R. A. DeCandido 28
> Breakdowns by Scott Ciencin omnibus 25-28
> Aftermath by Christopher L. Bennett 29
> Ishtar Rising Book 1 by Michael A. Martin   30
> Ishtar Rising Book 2 by Michael A. Martin   31
> Buying Time by Robert Greenberger   32
> Collective Hindsight Book 1 by Aaron Rosenberg  33
> Collective Hindsight Book 2 by Aaron Rosenberg  34
> The Demon Book 1 by Loren Coleman   35
> The Demon Book 2 by Loren Coleman   36
> Aftermath by Christopher L. Bennett omnibus 29-36
> Ring Around the Sky by Allyn Gibson 37
> Orphans by Kevin Killiany   38
> Grand Designs (novella) by Dayton Ward  39
> Failsafe by David Mack  40
> Bitter Medicine by Dave Galanter    41
> Sargasso Sector by Paul Kupperberg  42
> Grand Designs by Dayton Ward    omnibus 37-42
> Paradise Interrupted by John S. Drew    43
> Where Time Stands Still by Dayton Ward  44
> The Art of the Deal by Glenn Greenberg  45
> Spin by J. Steven York  46
> Creative Couplings, Part 1 by Glenn Hauman  47
> Creative Couplings, Part 2 by Glenn Hauman  48
> Small World by David Mack   49
> Creative Couplings by David Mack    omnibus 43-49
> Malefictorum by Terri Osborne   50
> Lost Time by Ilsa J. Bick   51
> Identity Crisis by John J. Ordover  52
> Fables of the Prime Directive by Cory Rushton   53
> Security by Keith R. A. DeCandido   54
> Wounds, Book 1 by Ilsa J. Bick  55
> Wounds, Book 2 by Ilsa J. Bick  56
> Wounds by Ilsa J. Bick  omnibus 50-56
> Out of the Cocoon by William Leisner    57
> Star Trek: Honor (Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers Book 58) by Kevin Killiany    58
> Blackout by Phaedra M. Weldon   59
> The Cleanup by Robert T. Jeschonek  60
> Out of the Cocoon by William Leisner    omnibus 57-60
> Progress by Terri Osborne   61
> The Future Begins by Michael Schuster   62
> Echoes of Coventry by Richard C. White  63
> Distant Early Warning by Dayton Ward    64
> 10 is Better Than 01 by Heather Jarman  65
> Many Splendors by Keith R. A. DeCandido 66
> What's Past by Terri Osborne    omnibus 61-66
> Turn the Page by Dayton Ward    COE #1
> Troubleshooting by Robert Greenberger   COE #2
> The Light by Jeff D. Jacques    COE #3
> The Art of the Comeback by Glenn Greenberg  COE #4
> Signs from Heaven by Phaedra M. Weldon  COE #5
> Ghost by Ilsa J. Bick   COE #6
> Remembrance of Things Past, Book I by Terri Osborne COE #7
> Remembrance of Things Past: Book II by Terri Osborne    COE #8
> Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers: What's Past
> Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers: Foundations
> Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers: Interphase
> Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers: Collective Hindsight
> Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers: The Demon
> Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers: Ishtar Rising
> <sub><sup>*- [Starfleet Corps of Engineers - LibraryThing](https://www.librarything.com/series/Star+Trek%3A+Starfleet+Corps+of+Engineers)*</sup></sub>

Worth noting: this list includes 13 Omnibus editions which bring the list of actual works down to 74.